How to read data from real Serial Port with Xamarin Forms on Android?
I need to read data from serial port, but NOT by an usb-rs232 adapter like many other question that I found here on S.O. I've an android 11 device with a real serial port, and I need to read data from it. Is there any way to do that by xamarin forms?

if there are "many other questions" on the topic, why aren't you using the existing answers?

@Jason Because as I wrote, the other questions and answers are on using a usb adapter, and I have a real db9 serial port on my device, not and usb one.

According to this Android doesn’t have native RS232 support

The OS adds shim/emulation software to ensure that a USB-serial adapter can be accessed in the same manner by userspace as a "real" serial port implemented with a UART .

@Jason Are you telling me that there aren't devices with RS232 onboard or that devices with onboard RS232 have to be handled as  USB-rs232 adapter? Or that  the real port is not usable^?

I'm saying that it appears that Android does not have native support for RS232, so any device that has one probably has some sort of driver or additional API provided by the manufacturer.   You should check the official Android docs to confirm, as well as the docs for your specific device.

Found out that producer provide a jar library to easily access the hw.
